# Nothing in /sys/class/bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Using Arch Linux and a bluetooth USB dongle identified as RTL8192CU.

Have all the recommended bluez packages installed and a few others besides:

```
extra/bluez 5.51-2 [installed]
  Daemons for the bluetooth protocol stack
extra/bluez-libs 5.51-2 [installed]
  Deprecated libraries for the bluetooth protocol stack
extra/bluez-qt 5.63.0-1 (kf5) [installed]
  Qt wrapper for Bluez 5 DBus API
extra/bluez-utils 5.51-2 [installed]
  Development and debugging utilities for the bluetooth protocol stack
community/bluez-tools 0.2.0-4 [installed]
  A set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for Linux
local/bluez-hciconfig 5.50-1 [installed]
  deprecated hciconfig tool from bluez
local/bluez-hcitool 5.45-1 [installed]
  deprecated rfcomm tool from bluez
```

I have been following the wikis from Arch Linux: [Bluetooth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Debugging) and [Bluetooth Headset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Legacy_documentation:_ALSA,_bluez5_and_PulseAudio_method)

Initially I had problems starting the bluetooth.service in systemd. It would not start if /sys/class/bluetooth was absent. I managed to force this to happen by adding btusb in a file in /etc/modules-load.d. I now have a directory called /sys/class/bluetooth, but this remains resolutely empty.

In dmesg I can see that the adapter is identified and the microcode loaded.

```
[   23.984058] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   24.072147] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   24.073623] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   24.074935] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   24.076401] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   24.077927] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
```

I think the correct modules are loaded:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   28672  2
fuse                  139264  3
rtl8xxxu              139264  0
rtl8192cu              94208  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     69632  1
rtl_usb                24576  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        65536  1 rtl8192cu
snd_hda_codec_via      24576  1
rtlwifi               126976  3 rtl8192c_common,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
snd_hda_codec_generic    94208  1 snd_hda_codec_via
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
mac80211              999424  4 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu,rtlwifi,rtl8xxxu
saa7134_alsa           28672  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
cfg80211              856064  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
i915                 2326528  26
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
saa7134               192512  1 saa7134_alsa
input_leds             16384  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
joydev                 28672  0
mousedev               24576  0
drm_kms_helper        212992  1 i915
drm                   516096  15 drm_kms_helper,i915
tveeprom               28672  1 saa7134
coretemp               20480  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 saa7134
intel_gtt              24576  1 i915
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
videobuf2_dma_sg       16384  1 saa7134
agpgart                53248  2 intel_gtt,drm
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_dma_sg
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 saa7134
snd_hda_codec         159744  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_via
kvm                   778240  0
videobuf2_common       57344  2 saa7134,videobuf2_v4l2
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_core          102400  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_via
videodev              237568  4 v4l2_common,saa7134,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
mc                     61440  4 videodev,saa7134,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common
rc_core                57344  1 saa7134
r8169                  94208  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
realtek                20480  1
libphy                 98304  2 r8169,realtek
mei_wdt                16384  0
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
snd_pcm               135168  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,saa7134_alsa,snd_hda_core
asus_wmi               36864  1 eeepc_wmi
snd_timer              40960  1 snd_pcm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
ppdev                  24576  0
mei_hdcp               24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd                   110592  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_via,saa7134_alsa,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                28672  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
mei_me                 45056  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
mei                   122880  5 mei_wdt,mei_hdcp,mei_me
parport_pc             53248  0
i2c_i801               36864  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
parport                61440  2 parport_pc,ppdev
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
evdev                  24576  12
mac_hid                16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           16384  0
intel_uncore          147456  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
wmi                    36864  2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
sg                     40960  0
crypto_user            16384  0
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             675840  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  7 asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
ip_tables              36864  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
ext4                  770048  3
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  135168  1 ext4
uas                    28672  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usb_storage            77824  1 uas
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   143360  2 usbhid,hid_generic
sr_mod                 28672  0
cdrom                  73728  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 57344  6
ata_generic            16384  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
ata_piix               36864  4
libata                282624  3 ata_piix,pata_acpi,ata_generic
xhci_pci               20480  0
ehci_pci               20480  0
scsi_mod              249856  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sg,sr_mod
xhci_hcd              278528  1 xhci_pci
crc32c_intel           24576  6
ehci_hcd               98304  1 ehci_pci
```